# Newsletter top question bug

Tags: support, top-questions, newsletter

I have just received the newsletter, and one of the top questions was [How to analyze a link to figure out the actual link](https://superuser.com/questions/320239/how-to-analyze-a-link-to-figure-out-the-actual-link?newsletter=1&nlcode=9035%7ccb83). It said I had answered the question.

It's nice I guess, but my answer was not marked as such, and it was not the only answer (though it was the upvoted the most, it was only by 3).

Was this intentional?

Comment: your answer does have the highest number of votes.

Comment: So that's what answered means? even if another answer was marked as the answer?

Comment: isn't it under top questions list?

Comment: Isn't what under top questions list?

Answer (score 3):

Given that the newsletter is intended to top questions & answers, I don't consider it as a bug for the fact that your answer, which was highest voted, was shown in the answered by column. You *have* answered that, haven't you?

Comment: yes, but its not definative unless it was marked as such

Comment: @soandos actually, we've discussed a similar thing in the past in regards to abandoned questions (where the question author leaves and doesn't return).  The best (and most correct) answer is the most up-voted one in most cases, *not* the one that particular question author chose.